# Jquery if variable == string in xml

Tags: jquery, xml, if-statement

Been trying to get this if-else statement to work, but every time I refresh the page `#thechange` is ALWAYS set to `'nochg'`.

Any ideas guys?

```
$j(document).ready(function () {
  $j.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "../funds-data/funds.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parseXml
  });
});

function parseXml(xml) {
  $j(xml).find("Symbol2").each(function () {
    var Pos = $j(this).children("Positive").text();
    alert(Pos);
    $j("#thenav").append($j(this).children("Nav").text() + "<!--other html-->");
    $j("#thechange").append($j(this).children("Change").text() + "<!--other html-->");
    $j("#thedate").append($j(this).children("Date").text() + "<!--other html-->");
    if (Pos == "Y") {
      $j("#thechange").attr('class', 'positivechg');
    } else if (Pos == "N") {
      $j("#thechange").attr('class', 'negativechg');
    } else {
      $j("#thechange").attr('class', 'nochg');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: you could replace `"Y".length` with `1`, though it won't make any difference. `"Y".length` will always be `1`. Same with `"N".length`, so is `Pos` is equal to one, it goes into the first conditional, else it goes to the else.

Comment: The XML text for the "Positive" node is set to either "Y" or "N".  I can't change it to 1.

Comment: That's my point. It's "Y" or "N", so it will never equal 1. "N".length returns 1. "Y".length returns 1. you are comparying "Y" to 1 which will always be false. minitech's answer also explains this and tells you how to fix it. simply remove `.length`.

Comment: Yeah, I know.  I got rid of the .length on both.  Thanks for the insight Kevin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"Y".length` and `"N".length` are both the same - `1`. I think you probably meant to compare `Pos` to `"Y"` or `"N"` themselves.

Comment: Tried that earlier.  No dice.  :(

Comment: The proper info from the XML note.  Page loads, popup with just the letter N.  I close it, but the class for #thechange stays at 'nochg'.

Comment: @Daveable: Put quotes around it: `alert("'" + Pos + "'");`. Any spaces?

Comment: Nope.  Man, was hoping that was it.

Comment: @Daveable: So `Pos.length` is `1`, it's definitely an uppercase `N`, and your `else if` definitely looks like `else if(Pos == "N")`?

Comment: @Daveable: How many `<Symbol2>`s are there in the document? And this one is the last one, right?

Comment: Ah, now we're getting somewhere.There are many <Symbol2> nodes.  This is the first one of 3.  It has a parent node of <RiskParityFund> which is the only one of its kind.  Should I target that instead?

Comment: THAT DID IT!  minitech, you are awesome!  I had to add another child for all my childeren calls like this. `.children("Symbol2").children("Positive")`
but then it worked amazingly!!!